# How a string of text every other two lines in a foreach loop in PHP? (retrieving records from a database)

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a "boxing records" database for a school project. The loop retrieves records from a SQL statement. I want to add a "VS" string of text between every other two lines in order to show records outputted somewhat like this.

### Upcoming Fights

Sergey Kovalev (28-0-25) 
VS 
Jean Pascal (30-3-17)

Another Boxer (123-0-5)
VS
Some Boxer (123-3-1)

However, my current loop outputs like this

Sergey Kovalev (28-0-25)
VS 
Jean Pascal (30-3-17)
VS
Another Boxer (123-3-1)
VS
Some Other Boxer (123-3-1)
VS

The loop I currently have is the following

```
foreach($records as $record) {
              $i = 0;
              echo $record['name'] . " (" . $record['wins'] . "-" . $record['losses'] . "-" . $record['kos'] . ")" . "<br>";
              $i=$i*2;
              if($i%2 == 0)
              {
                echo "VS <br/>";
              }
              else{
                echo "<br />";
              }
```

I know I could probably change the SQL in order to display two fighters in the same row, and then append "vs" on the echo, but I thought that just modifying the for loop would work by using a variable counter $i. I thought it would be pretty easy to make the "VS" appear between every two rows but im missing something in my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment value of `$i` by one rather than multiplying it by 2 and initialize `$i` outside `foreach` loop.

```
$i = 0; // Initialize counter here
foreach($records as $record) {

    echo $record['name'] . " (" . $record['wins'] . "-" . $record['losses'] . "-" . $record['kos'] . ")" . "<br>";

    if($i%2 == 0)
    {
        echo "VS <br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br />";
    }
    $i++; // Increment counter here
}
```

Comment: I have tried incrementing by 1 but I totally forgot about having to initialize it outside the loop. Thanks a lot